# how I can specify the things I write on the EditText....!

Tags: android, android-edittext

I want to type on EditText with custom keyboard. Lets say I want to write number 1, is there any way so that I can disable number 1 after I wrote it. Even the user tries to press number 1 from the keyboard it won't write but if he delete any number using backspace, he can use deleted number again once.  Is it possible to do that for numbers 0-9 ????

public class BasicOnKeyboardActionListener implements OnKeyboardActionListener {

```
private Activity mTargetActivity;


public BasicOnKeyboardActionListener(Activity targetActivity) {
    mTargetActivity = targetActivity;
}

@Override
public void swipeUp() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void swipeRight() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void swipeLeft() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void swipeDown() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onText(CharSequence text) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onRelease(int primaryCode) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onPress(int primaryCode) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onKey(int primaryCode, int[] keyCodes) {
    long eventTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    KeyEvent event = new KeyEvent(eventTime, eventTime,
            KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, primaryCode, 0, 0, 0, 0,
            KeyEvent.FLAG_SOFT_KEYBOARD | KeyEvent.FLAG_KEEP_TOUCH_MODE);

    mTargetActivity.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
}
```

CustomKeyboardView.class

```
public class CustomKeyboardView extends KeyboardView {

public CustomKeyboardView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public void showWithAnimation(Animation animation) {
    animation.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });

    setAnimation(animation);
}
```

KeyboardWidgetTutorialActivity.class

```
public class KeyboardWidgetTutorialActivity extends Activity {

private CustomKeyboardView mKeyboardView;
private View mTargetView;
private Keyboard mKeyboard;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    mKeyboard = new Keyboard(this, R.xml.keyboard);
    mTargetView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.target);
    mTargetView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            showKeyboardWithAnimation();
            return true;
        }
    });

    mKeyboardView = (CustomKeyboardView) findViewById(R.id.keyboard_view);
    mKeyboardView.setKeyboard(mKeyboard);
    mKeyboardView
            .setOnKeyboardActionListener(new BasicOnKeyboardActionListener(
                    this));
}


private void showKeyboardWithAnimation() {
    if (mKeyboardView.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
        Animation animation = AnimationUtils
                .loadAnimation(KeyboardWidgetTutorialActivity.this,
                        R.anim.slide_in_bottom);
        mKeyboardView.showWithAnimation(animation);
    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
         if (mKeyboardView.isShown()) {
          mKeyboardView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
           super.onBackPressed();
        }
     }

  }
}
```

this is the main xml

```
  <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/container" android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"     android:layout_above="@+id/keyboard_view">
    <EditText android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/target"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>

<it.anddev.tutorial.CustomKeyboardView
    android:id="@+id/keyboard_view" android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">   </it.anddev.tutorial.CustomKeyboardView>

  </RelativeLayout>
```

keyboard xml

```
 <Keyboard xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:keyWidth="33%p" android:horizontalGap="0px"
android:verticalGap="0px" android:keyHeight="150dip">

<Row>
    <Key android:codes="8" android:keyLabel="1" android:keyEdgeFlags="left"      />
    <Key android:codes="9" android:keyLabel="2" />
    <Key android:codes="10" android:keyLabel="3" />
    <Key android:codes="67" android:keyIcon="@drawable/sym_keyboard_delete"
        android:iconPreview="@drawable/sym_keyboard_delete"
        android:keyEdgeFlags="right" />
</Row>

<Row>
    <Key android:codes="11" android:keyLabel="4" android:keyEdgeFlags="left" />
    <Key android:codes="12" android:keyLabel="5" />
    <Key android:codes="13" android:keyLabel="6" />
    <Key android:codes="66" android:keyEdgeFlags="right"
        android:keyIcon="@drawable/sym_keyboard_feedback_return"
        android:iconPreview="@drawable/sym_keyboard_feedback_return" />
</Row>

<Row>
    <Key android:codes="14" android:keyLabel="7" android:keyEdgeFlags="left" />
    <Key android:codes="15" android:keyLabel="8" />
    <Key android:codes="16" android:keyLabel="9"    android:keyEdgeFlags="right" />
    <Key android:codes="7" android:keyLabel="0" />

    </Row>


  </Keyboard>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pike is correct using textwatcher would help you however, to achieve this, you can use a condition that would stop the app from displaying the number that is already inside the edittext.

EDIT:

```
String textContainer = "";
int length = 0;
int prevLength = 0;
    editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int start, int count, int after) {
            textContainer = s.toString();
            prevLength = s.length();
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int start, int before, int count) {
            }
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
          length = s.length();
           if(!textContainer.isEmpty()){
                if(s.length() > 1) {
                    if(prevLength < length) {
                        if (!textContainer.contains(s.toString().subSequence(length - 1, length))) {
                            length = s.length();
                        } else {
                            phoneNumberEditText.getText().delete(length - 1, length);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }else{
                textContainer = s.toString();
            }


            }
        });
```

Haven't tested this, but this should give you an idea.

Comment: and that is i want but i don't know how to do it

Comment: should i put in textcontainer ("1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0") ?

Comment: I updated the answer, you shouldn't put any numbers now.

Comment: Forgot to add the length inside if. Check the updated answer.

Comment: i can't solve it ...! y always writeing else without if and we have if :O

Comment: the second if is missing a close parenthesis ")" add one.

Comment: still the same :( i can write 112233 :(

Comment: I uninstall the app and reinstall it now i have
                                                                       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.mike.a12345/com.example.mike.a12345.KeyboardWidgetActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: check my code if u want i edited but didn't put ur code here

Comment: thank you but if u found any solution please tell me,,!

Comment: i guess it is the editText so i change the s with my edittext now its writing 1 number only just  2 or 3 or 4 or ............. ( i cant write 1234 together)
i want to free what i write but dont want to appear two 2s or 3s

Comment: can tell me what happening here dude :D i didn't understand

Comment: First you're getting a value from the current text and its previous length, after the changes, you check if the new text length is greater than the previous so you would know that the user has added a character. After that you check if the last added character is already existing within the current text, if it is existing then you delete it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to disable it from keyboard directly. but, instead You can always use `Textwatcher`  on your `edittext` to check what you are writing each time you change text inside edittext.

```
   yourEdittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int start, int count, int after) {
            String oldText = yourEdittext.getText().toString();
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int start, int before, int count) {
          String newText = yourEdittext.getText().toString();
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
          String newText = yourEdittext.getText().toString();
        }
    });
```

Comment: I want when the user wrote number for example 1234 the number 1234 disable so he can't wrote it again until he backspace it for example he did just for number 4 then  when he press on number 4 write just once

Comment: it simple when i write 1 i don't want to appear any number 1 again even if press on the key but i don't know the way i searched the net for 2 days for disable it from keyboard

Answer (score 0):

Create A custom Keyboard, and disable the Button once pressed. And on Backspace read the last word Enable it back

Use Fragment for displaying or hiding your keyboard. You will have to overide OnFocus of edit text to not Display default Keyboard, but your keyboard.

Comment: actually i searched whole net i didn't find a code that display 1 button from my custom keyboard can u help me with the code sry im newbie

Comment: Your keyboard which you have to design will be an another layout. add buttons for these numbers and put a onclickListener to all the buttons.

getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);

Use this to hide the default Keyboard.

Comment: my keyboard is an xml file custom keyboard i putted just numbers in it and backspace and enter buttons

Comment: Yup Then connect it with java file as you connect activities and stuff and asign the click listeners.

Comment: connect it with java file ?? i don't follow u i dont understand this

Comment: Create a java file extending activity/ Fragment (Whichever you used for your Keyboard). And give OnclickListener to your Keyoboard the same way to give it to any other view

Comment: i'm using custom not the default but i don't know how to disable the button it's not like normal button to put setenable

Answer (score 0):

To check everysingle edittext by textwatcher is incorrect for your purposes. If you need a keyboard which won't enter some value twice in all inputfields you have in the app, when you should implement your own keyboard, like Shuddh mentioned.

Here is the tutorial how to build such keyboard:

https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-custom-keyboard-on-android--cms-22615

Just a notice, there is a method onKey() - there you should check if value was already entered and ignore it. In order to check value there is InputConnection object which allows you to get access to the views like edittext which are currently active.

Comment: I have custom keyboard and yes i have onKey() check my code...!

Comment: and I have just 1 EditText

Comment: In case you need only 1 edittext with such behavior, then textwatcher is OK :) just take the value, check it and do the trick

Comment: i tried the codes  Vryin wrotes not working and I can't find any other example and i don't know how to put the values that I enter and disable it if it's exist :(